# Change activity that opens on clicking pushbots notification in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, pushbots

I am using Pushbots to send a notification to my phonegap application, whenever I click the sent notification index.html opens up, how to change that to say next_page.html. That is when I click on the notification next_page.html should open up.

There is not a lot of documentation available for Pushbots. And I couldn't find anything for this in the phonegap documentation.

Comment: Did you fixed that issue?

Comment: No I could not, as a workaround I put the information I wanted in index.html